# Is there a way to add a function in python?

Tags: python, function

Is there any way that I could have a function inside of a function e.g. `def example.example2()`? How could I achieve this? I am trying to make a big file for all of my usual  imports.

I have tried `def example.example` but it doesn't work.

I want it to be like *`time.stop(1)`*

Comment: [ask] and [mre] Use a class or a module/package?

Comment: How would I do that? (sorry I am a beginner)

Comment: Read a tutorial. [ask]

Comment: @Julien MREs are only required for debugging questions. As this is a how-to question, no MRE is required. While it may be basic/lack effort, it does not appear to be against site rules in a way that make sit close-worthy (unless there is a duplicate out there somewhere).

Comment: @TylerH "I have tried def example.example but it doesn't work" with no more info is always followed by a link to [mre] in my books.

Comment: @Julien "your books" are wrong, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question literally:

```
>>> def hello():
...   print("hello")
... 
>>> def world():
...   print("world")
... 
>>> hello.world = world
>>> 
>>> hello()
hello
>>> hello.world()
world
```

but don't do this.

learn about classes instead because this is literally terrible and will make everyone who reads it sad